# I want to know how double quotes are used in C

Tags: c, string

In the code `char * str = "hello";`, I understand that code `"hello"` is to allocate the word *hello* to any other memory and then put the first value of that allocated memory into the variable str.

But when I use the code `char str[10] = "hello";`, I understood that the word *hello* is included in each element of the array.
If then, on the top, the code `"hello"` returns the address of the memory
and on the bottom, the code `"hello"` returns the word h e l l o \n.

I want to know why they are different and if I'm wrong, I want to know what double quotes return.

Comment: Single quotes are for single characters. Double quotes are for string literals. You are getting h e l l o \n because that's the string literal representation of "hello"

Comment: @lasfkjasdfjlasfjkl : Where is your code to prove your assumptions?

Comment: @WolfgangRoth: What? There is no need for code here. Debugging questions should have an [mre]. Not every question needs code.

Comment: Why should the two not be different?  What's surprising about different code having different meaning?

Answer (score 2):

C is a bit quirky. You have two distinct use cases here. But let's first start with what `"hello"` is.

Your `"hello"` in the program source code is a *character string literal.* That is a *character sequence* enclosed in double quotes. When the compiler is compiling this source code, it appends a zero byte to the sequence, so that standard library functions like `strlen()` can work on it. The resulting zero-terminated sequence is then used by the compiler to "initialize an **array of static storage duration** and length just sufficient to contain the sequence array of constant characters" (n1570 ISO C draft, 6.4.5/6). That length is 6: The 5 characters h, e, l, l and o as well as the appended zero byte.

"Static storage duration" means that the array exists the entire time the program is running (as opposed to objects with *automatic* local storage duration, e.g. local variables, and those with *dynamic* storage duration, which are created via `malloc()` or `calloc()`).

You can memorize the address of that array, as in `char *str = "hello";`. This address will point to valid memory during the lifetime of the program.

The second use case is a special syntax for initializing character arrays. It is just syntactic sugar for this common use case, and a deviation from the fact that you cannot normally initialize arrays with arrays.<sup>1</sup>

This time you don't define a pointer, you define a proper array of 10 chars. You then use the string literal to initialize it. You always can use the generic method to initialize a character array by listing the individual array elements, separated by commas, in curly braces (by the way, this generic method works also for the other kind of compound types, namely structs):

`char str[10] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };`

This is entirely equivalent to

`char str[10] = "hello";`

Now your array has more elements (10) than the number of characters in the initializing array produced from the string literal (6); the standard stipulates that "subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration". Those global and static variables are initialized with zero, which means that the character array `str` ends with 4 zero characters.

It is immediately obvious why Dennis Ritchie added the somewhat anti-paradigmatic initialization of character arrays via a string literal, probably after the second time he had to do it with the generic array initialization syntax. Designing your own language has its benefits.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, <strike>`static char src[] = "123"; char dest[] = src;`</strike> doesn't work. You have to use [`strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy).

Answer (score 1):

The initialization:

```
char * str = "hello";
```

in most C implementations makes sure that the string `hello` is placed in a **constant data section** of the executable memory. Exactly six bytes are written, the last one being the string terminator `'\0'`.
`str` char pointer contains the address of the first character `'h'`, so that anyone accessing the string knows that the following bytes have to be read until the terminator character is found.

The other initialization

```
char str[10] = "hello";  // <-- string must be enclosed in double quotes
```

is very similar, as `str` points to the first character of the string and that the following characters are written in the following memory locations (included the string terminator).
**But**:

1. Even if only six bytes are *explicitly* initialized, ten bytes are allocated because that's the size of the array. In this case, the four trailing bytes will contain zeroes
2. Data is not constant and can be changed, while in the previous example it wasn't possible because such initialization, in most C implementations, instructs the compiler to use a constant data section

Comment: Re “… makes sure that the string hello is placed in a **constant data section**”: This is not true in every C implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't recall any implementation in which this is not true, but I trust your encyclopedic knowledge of the C standard. Could you please provide a counter-example in which the described behavior is not true?

Comment: There is no partial initialization in C.  If you initialize a `char` array with a shorter string literal then all the trailing bytes of the array are *definitely* initialized to zeroes.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: Rudimentary hardware designed for single-purpose tasks instead if multiple uses may not have memory protection and hence cannot put string literals in a “constant data section.” (It could be a place you call a constant data section because that is the intent to use it for, but it would not be behaviorally different from other memory.)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up some things:

```
char str[10] = "hello';
```

This does not even compile: when you start with a double-quote, you should end with one:

```
char str[10] = "hello";
```

In memory, this has following effect:

```
str[0] : h
str[1] : e
str[2] : l
str[3] : l
str[4] : o
str[5] : 0 (the zero character constant)
str[6] : xxx
str[7] : xxx
str[8] : xxx
str[9] : xxx
```

(By `xxx`, I mean that this can be anything)

As a result, the code will not return `hello\n` (with an end-of-line character), just `hello\0` (the zero character).

The double quotes just mention the beginning and the ending of a string constant and return nothing.

Comment: Well, str[5] == 0.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: thanks for your remark, I corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Re “By xxx, I mean that this can be anything”: If any part of an aggregate is initialized, the parts without initializers are default initialized (in the same way as static objects), which would be to initialize with zero values in this case.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: This looks very dangerous to me: I always initialise my variables, arrays, ..., as you never know you might into a situation where initialisations are not done, and you're stuck with garbage values. Therefore, even if the programming language handles some initialisations by itself, never rely on this.

Comment: @Dominique `str[6] : xxx` is incorrect.  There is no partial initialization in C. `str[6 /* to 9 */] : 0`.  Dangerous or not, it is how C is specified.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I don't say that anything is initialised: the value `xxx` is just the value which is present at that time in memory, it has not been changed. by the way, who is this Monica you guys want to reinstate? :-)

Comment: @Dominique With `char str[10] = "hello";` `str[6 /* to 9 */]` are only 0 at that point, not "the value which is present at that time in memory".

Comment: @Dominique [Who is Monica?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393046/2410359)

Comment: @Dominique That incident was so bad it should be a constant thorn in SE's flesh as a reminder to never betray a user in such an ugly fashion ever again. The worst thing is that it was never satisfactorily resolved. SE never publicly admitted that they had made a mistake. Monica and SE eventually arrived at a settlement but I could never get over it, really. If there were a second SO I wouldn't be here. They *still* should go, send her flowers, apologize, and reinstate her.

Comment: @Dominique With respect to zero-initialization of objects with static storage duration, and zero-initialization of subobjects which are not explicitly initialized: It is perfectly fine to rely on it.

Comment: @Dominique By the way, another angle about user names is that you can always click the user name to see their profile. People with unusual names often have information about it on their profile page.

Comment: Re “you never know you might into a situation where initialisations are not done”: All the compilers that attempt to conform to the C standard have deviations of various kinds, but they are typically minor or esoteric. None that I know of disobey this clear rule about initialization. If somebody is using a compiler that violates that rule, it is a considerable deviation from the standard, and they would have to worry about how the compiler handles the entirety of their program, not just initialization.